# Trident arrow in Tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, draw

I am looking for basic code which will produce three nodes, one above the other two, with a trident arrow going from the top node to the bottom two, like in the picture below.

I can get arrows and spacing using things like

```
 \node [block3d, below right=3cm and 0.1cm of wp4.south] (t9) {T2.2.2};
```

and

```
\draw[->] (ob1.south -| wp1.north) -- (wp1.north);
```

But the trident style? Do I create a special arrow going down, the two more going right then left, then down?

[image]

Comment: There's no such thing as trident arrow in the basic stuff but once you put your three nodes under the root, you can do something like `draw[->] (root) --++ (0,-1) -| (child one)`, `draw[->] (root) -- (child two)` and `draw[->] (root) --++ (0,-1) -| (child three)`,

Comment: A suggestion: you might see if something cane done  with `mathabx`: it defines a `\pitchfork`  and a `\Neptune` symbols, that look like the extremity of a trident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: trident fork arrow]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
        box/.style={
            rectangle,
            minimum width=15mm
            ,minimum height=1cm,
            draw,
            line width=2pt,
            cyan!50!blue,
            text=black},
        arr/.style={
            line width=2pt,
            cyan!50!blue,
            -Stealth}
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[box] (root) {ROOT};
        \node[box,below left = of root] (child one) {ONE};
        \node[box,below = of root] (child two) {TWO};
        \node[box,below right = of root] (child three) {THREE}; 
        
        \draw[arr] (root) --++ (0,-.85) -| (child one);
        \draw[arr] (root) -- (child two);           
        \draw[arr] (root) --++ (0,-.85) -| (child three);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.